# Mimicking position(node-set) in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, position, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

XSLT 2.0 offers the benefit of passing a node-set param as part of the position() function.  Unfortunately, that is not available in XSLT 1.0.  Is there a way to mimic this behavior?

For example, given this XML:

```
<wishlists>
  <wishlist name="Games">
    <product name="Crash Bandicoot"/>
    <product name="Super Mario Brothers"/>
    <product name="Sonic the Hedgehog"/>
  </wishlist>
  <wishlist name="Movies">
    <product name="Back to the Future"/>
  </wishlist>
</wishlists>
```

and this XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position(/wishlists/wishlist/product)"/>
```

the value "4" would be returned when processing the final "Back to the Future" node.

Unfortunately, the closest I seem to be able to get with XSLT 1.0 is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I would get a value of "1" in the same "Back to the Future" node, as opposed to the "4" value that I really want.

Comment: What XSLT 2.0 processor are you using that allows arguments in `position()`?

Comment: I thought I had read that was possible in XSLT 2.0.  Maybe I misunderstood what I read (or perhaps misread count() as position() or something).  If I'm mistaken about XSLT 2.0, my question still stands on how to go about what I'm trying to do. :)

Comment: Since we don't know what semantics you are imagining for the position(node-set()) function, it's hard to tell you how to implement it.

Comment: I thought my example was pretty clear.  Or at least it was clear enough for two other users to provide correct answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [preceding axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <product position="{count(preceding::product) + 1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </product>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your XML input produces:

```
<wishlists>
   <wishlist name="Games">
      <product position="1" name="Crash Bandicoot"/>
      <product position="2" name="Super Mario Brothers"/>
      <product position="3" name="Sonic the Hedgehog"/>
   </wishlist>
   <wishlist name="Movies">
      <product position="4" name="Back to the Future"/>
   </wishlist>
</wishlists>
```

Comment: Awesome, sounds like the preceding axis is definitely what I was looking for.  Will try it now and mark as answer as soon as I see it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> XSLT 2.0 offers the benefit of passing a node-set param as part of the
>   position() function.

This statement is wrong. The `position()` function has no arguments -- either in XPath 1.0 or in XPath 2.0, which XSLT 2.0 uses.

**What you want is**:

```
count(preceding::product) +1
```

or, alternatively, the `xsl:number` instruction can be used.

**Here is a demonstration of both these methods**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLastProd" select=
  "//product[@name='Back to the Future']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="count($vLastProd/preceding::product) +1"/>
=========
<xsl:text/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vLastProd"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product">
   <xsl:number level="any" count="product"/>    
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<wishlists>
    <wishlist name="Games">
        <product name="Crash Bandicoot"/>
        <product name="Super Mario Brothers"/>
        <product name="Sonic the Hedgehog"/>
    </wishlist>
    <wishlist name="Movies">
        <product name="Back to the Future"/>
    </wishlist>
</wishlists>
```

**the wanted, correct result is obtained using both methods -- and output**:

```
4
=========
4
```

**Note**: The result of `xsl:number` needs to be captured inside the body of a variable, if it will not be output directly.

Comment: Yeah, DevNull mentioned that in the question comments, and I obviously misinterpreted something I read somewhere!

Comment: @MattHuggins: Yes, I have provided two different methods to obtain what you refer as "position" -- both of them can be used either with XSLT 1.0 or with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  When I first wrote my comment, your edits weren't there. ;)